# Magento 2.4.4 - Category page show Normal and Special price of selected simple product of configurable product

Tags: magento2.4, product-prices, configurable-product-options

I am using Magento 2.4.4 and I want to show the normal price and special price of the selected simple products of configurable products on the Product listing page.
I am using configurable dropdown options so I could not use swatch-renderer.js to customize.

Please suggest any solution to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using amasty extensions or configurable products?

Comment: No, I am using the Amasty extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `final_price.phtml` from

**Vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

to

**Vendor/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

change (around line 26)

```
<?php if (!$block->isProductList() && $block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

**with**

```
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
```

(**special_price** will display)

and replace

```
<span class="old-price sly-old-price no-display">
```

by

```
<span class="old-price sly-old-price">
```

(remove the **no-display** class)

Let me know if any query

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: It works for me thanks @mohit